# Does any traversal of a tree work any time?

Tags: algorithm, tree, tree-traversal

This might be more of a theoretical (or mathematical) question:

Given a finite tree, if I can do one operation (say, finding lowest common ancestor) using a post-order traversal of a tree, then is it guaranteed that I would be able to find the solution using any of the remaining two traversals as well (in-order and pre-order)?

If no, then how do we decide which traversal would work for a given situation?  If yes, then is 'ease of implementation' a factor when deciding which one to use?

Thanks!

**Edit**:  I am asking this question because sometimes it is not pretty straight forward to do some thing if we don't use a particular traversal.  For e.g., in [method 2 of this post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lowest-common-ancestor-binary-tree-set-1/), we take into account the values returned by the left and right subtrees (all good because we are using a post-order traversal).  Had we used any other traversal, then it would not have been so straightforward.

Comment: Please edit details into the question, not as comments.

Comment: ... why is finding LCA related to post order traversal?

Comment: Also self contained question please. To avoid link rot.

Comment: @user202729, I never said that.  I am just saying that it is pretty straight-forward (in my opinion) if post-order traversal is used.  My precise question is - if I can do something by post-order then does it guarantee that it can be done by other traversals as well?

Comment: @user202729, my question is in no way related to the linked post.  It is just an example.  That's the reason I had commented that link earlier (and not included in the post at all).  Whether that link rots or not is not going to affect this question at all.

Comment: [No "_Thanks"_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @user202729, "thanks" for the link.  But I do not wish to get into the _debate_ - there's meta for that.  This single word in no-way mars the main intent of the post and so _I_ am good.  If _you_ want, please feel free to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, no.

Or at least, not efficiently. With enough scaffolding and chewing gum, you can build an algorithm which does multiple postorder traverses to effectively implements an inorder or preorder traverse (and vice versa and mix-and-match), but the multiple walks will be much less efficient than a single walk using an appropriate traverse order.

For many tree-based datastructures, there are many more than three possible walks, since there is no law of the universe which requires that the same traverse order be performed on every node of a tree. (This becomes quite obvious when you start to look at, for example, compilation of programs which have been parsed into abstract syntax trees.)

For complex tree walks, it is sometimes necessary to construct a data dependency graph which can be used to ensure that the required inputs to the computation(s) at each node are available at appropriate points in time. There are even cases where the tree walks themselves are created by program generators working on the output of such a dependency diagram.

If the algorithm does not mutate the tree, then any arbitrary computation order can be implemented by using lazy evaluation. In effect, that modifies the tree into the data dependency graph and then iteratively reduces the data dependency graph (if possible; if the graph is circular that won't work). However, that is not really a simplification.

Comment: Now this might be a vague question, but are there any guidelines (or just _anything_) that can be used to (even vaguely) find out which traversal would be preferable in a given context?

Comment: @j.doe the only guideline i can think of is to use your knowledge about data dependencies (which includes your knowledge about what exactly is stored in each node). That's a vague answer to a vague question, I guess. But it is also why we have jobs: when (if) everything becomes a known algorithm, who is going to pay us to think them up? :-)

Comment: Off-topic: I asked this question around 1 month back, when I visited your profile and happened to read the last paragraph - "_And I'm always looking for a good algorithm question ... one of those named after me; meanwhile, I collect other people's._"  I have not been able to get it out of my head since then (because I strongly feel the same).  Would you mind if I use it some where?  Like saying that it is my ambition as well in interviews, etc?  I would be grateful to you if you say yes. :)

Comment: @jdoe: be my guest